# TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in "{_id: 0, lessonName: Matematik}"

Tags: json, ajax

I am using mongoose. I've a Lesson schema like this :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var lessonSchema  = mongoose.Schema({
                _id: {type: Number, required:true, unique:true, max: 10},
                lessonName: {type: String, required: true, max: 100},      
});
var Lesson = mongoose.model('Lesson', lessonSchema);
module.exports = Lesson;
```

I'm sending an Array of JSON from the page like :

```
var lessonArray=[];
for (i=0;i < dersler.length;i++) {
    lessonArray.push("{_id: " + i + ", lessonName: " + dersler[i] + "}");
}
console.log("lessonArray: " + lessonArray + "-" + lessonArray.length)
return lessonArray;
$.ajax({
                     url: "http://localhost:3000/addlesson",
                     type: 'POST',
                     data: JSON.stringify(lessons),
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                     dataType: "json", 
                     success: function (msg) {
                              console.log("Başarılı Ajax Çağrısı")
                              },
                     error:   function (errormessage) {
                              console.log("Başarısız Ajax Çağrısı:")
                              }
                }).then(function(data) {
                    console.log('DB insert gelen cevap:' + data);
                });
```

On the node server I handle the POST like :

```
app.post("/addlesson", (req, res) => {
    //var myLessonList = new Lesson(JSON.parse(req.body[1]));
    var myLessonList = req.body;
    console.log("Lesson1:" + myLessonList[0]);
    var myData = Lesson(myLessonList[0]);
    console.log("Lesson11:" + myData);
    console.log("LessonList:" + myLessonList + '-' + req.body);
    Lesson.lessonName = req.body[1];
    console.log("LessonName:" + Lesson.lessonName);
/*      var myData = new Lesson(req.body);
    myData.save()
    .then(item => {
        res.send("item saved to database");
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send("unable to save to database:" + err);
    });
*/
res.send("Başarılı");
});
```

but at this line below it gives an type error

```
var myData = Lesson(myLessonList[0]);
```

I am trying to make AJAX post to server and get the body and get json array from it and then save the data to mongodb. But somehow it looks like there is an error from converting data from array to json or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue my be related with the fact that you are not actually sending a JSON array of objects but a JSON array of stings. I would suggest changing the lessonArray loop to something like the below to create the array:

`var lessonArray=[];
for (i=0;i < dersler.length;i++) {
    lessonArray.push({_id: i, lessonName: dersler[i]});
}`

And the JSON.stringify you have later in the code should handle making that into valid json.

Also depending on whether you are using a JSON parsing middleware in the backend or not, you may need to do a JSON.parse at the server as I can see you had at some point.